# ARM Linker error message "no source files - nothing to do", does not find existing symbols in library?

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors, linker, cortex-m

I am using a TMSp320F2888D from TI which feature an ARM Cortex processor. For some reason I am unable to build my project in Eclipse anymore even after resetting my code to an earlier commit.

When I try to build the project after I clean it I get the following error messages:

[image]

However, the missing symbols are located in a library that I include using the corresponding Linker flags.

The following commands verify that the symbols and library exist on my system:

```
nm ~/ti/C2000Ware_3_04_00_00_Software/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug/driverlib_cm.lib | grep Ethernet_rec
00000001 T Ethernet_receiveISR
00000001 T Ethernet_receivePacketCallback
nm ~/ti/C2000Ware_3_04_00_00_Software/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug/driverlib_cm.lib | grep Ethernet_tran
00000001 T Ethernet_transmitISR
```

I include the corresponding library and search path in Eclipse:

[image]

Looking at the Build Console, this is the last command issued before failure:

```
Building target: "enet_lwip_cm.out"
Invoking: ARM Linker
"/home/dvarx/ti/ccs1030/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS/bin/armcl" -mv7M4 --code_state=16 --float_support=none -me -O0 --opt_for_speed=0 --define=_FLASH --define=ccs -g --diag_warning=225 --gen_func_subsections=on --abi=eabi --ual -n -z -m"enet_lwip_cm.map" --heap_size=0x1000 --stack_size=2048 -i"/home/dvarx/ti/ccs1030/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS/lib" -i"/home/dvarx/ti/C2000Ware_3_04_00_00_Software/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug" -i"/home/dvarx/ti/ccs1030/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS/include" -i"/home/dvarx/ti/ccs1030/ccs/tools/compiler" -i"/home/dvarx/ti/C2000Ware_3_04_00_00_Software/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug" --reread_libs --warn_sections --xml_link_info="enet_lwip_cm_linkInfo.xml" --rom_model -o "enet_lwip_cm.out" "./comm_interface.obj" "./f2838xif.obj" "./fs.obj" "./httpd.obj" "./lwiplib.obj" "./main_tcp_interface_lwip.obj" "./pinout.obj" "./startup_ccs.obj" "./ustdlib.obj" "../2838x_flash_lnk_cm_lwip.cmd"  -l"/home/dvarx/ti/C2000Ware_3_04_00_00_Software/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug/driverlib_cm.lib" -l"/home/dvarx/ti/C2000Ware_3_04_00_00_Software/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug/driverlib_cm.lib" -llibc.a 
>> ERROR: no source files, nothing to do
Finished building target: "enet_lwip_cm.out"
```

I am not sure why the Linker would complain about missing source files since they seem to be provided in the command?

Comment: Just some guesses ... `ERROR: no source files, nothing to do` To me, _source_ files usually mean `.c` files. You didn't show the compile phase. However, if that's okay, then _source_ files would mean `.o` and/or `.obj` files. I'd look at the `.obj` vs `.lib` files to ensure that they have matching arch/machine types for arm (e.g. You're compiling for arm, but if the `.lib` files were for x86_64, they could be _silently_ skipped).

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment. It's true that the `.obj` files were not generated in the first place due to an incorrect compiler flag that was set.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. The problem was that the `-n` flag was set in the compiler. This caused the compiler to generate assembly files `.asm` instead of object files `.obj`. After removing this flag the project built correctly.